# sqlcmd does not work: Can't open lib libmsodbcsql.13.dylib

Tags: osx, sqlserver

I've installed `mssql-tools` and `msodbcsql`,

And I've symlinked `/usr/local/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib`

But sqlcmd still complains about missing lib,

```
%> sqlcmd -S IP
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib' : file not found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Some things maybe be unhappy with a symlink, can you try physically copying the file?

Comment: @thrig Same result

Comment: Hmm, what does running it under `dtruss` show?

Comment: Thanks @thrig! dtruss is super helpful, I need to symlink `/usr/local/homebrew/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib` as well, dtruss pointed that out

Comment: Ahh, lies, damned lies, and error messages.

Answer (score 3):

As @thrig says, I tried to `dtruss` to debug the problem,

```
sudo dtruss sqlcmd -S someserver
```

And from the output, sqlcmd attempts to read `/usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib` and failed.

Adding symlink of `libodbcinst.2.dylib` solved the problem, so it's actually caused by a missing dependency, sigh

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't happen on all our machines, but we did run into it today.
We ran

`brew install msodbcsql`

We encountered

`libmsodbcsql13.dylib not found`

We ran

`brew link msodbcsql`

This resulted in:

`4 symlinks created`

This fixed the issue for us.

Comment: Awesome .. this is much better

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

First of all try reinstalling the packages again:

```
brew tap microsoft/msodbcsql https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
ACCEPT_EULA=y brew reinstall --no-sandbox msodbcsql mssql-tools
```

Then if it's still happening, run:

```
cp -v "$(brew list msodbcsql | grep odbcinst.ini$)" ~/.odbcinst.ini
```

to copy the INI file which defines the location of SQL ODBC driver.

<sup>Bug report: [SQL Server : Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'](https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/3).</sup>

Then test your SQL setup by: `sqlcmd -S localhost` or `isql -v -k <connection-string>`.

See: [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).

#### Debugging

```
$ odbcinst -j # Verify the config.
$ sleep 20 && sqlcmd -S localhost & # Run `sqlcmd` in the background.
$ sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep -w sqlcmd | grep -e open -e access -e stat64
open              /Users/myuser/.odbcinst.ini                 
access            /usr/local/lib/ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
access            /lib>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                    
access            /usr/lib/ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server      
stat64            ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server               
stat64            /opt/X11/lib/ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server  
stat64            /usr/lib/ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
```

---

For Linux, see this Anaconda related issue: [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server can't open lib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41182415/55075).

Comment: This worked for me among all the solutions I read. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the `dtruss` trace produced the same output as described by daisy.

The location of the missing lib is with the unixodbc drivers.  You can install those with `brew install unixodbc` if you don't have them.  The link command and paths required for linking on my system were as follows:

`ln /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.6/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib 
    /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib`

Obviously, you may have a different version, but it should be located beneath the path `/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc`

After adding this link, I am able to connect to my local and remote SQL servers from the terminal.  I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: For 13 version need open ssl v 1.0.0 , you can try it.

brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb

Comment: Welcome to unix SE and hi! I don't quite find how your answer relates to the question. Would mind to elaborate?